# C# creating ".exe" with libraries

Tags: c#, dll, project

I'm using some dlls in my project. To make a '.exe' file i only used 'Released' in Solution Configurations. In my computer exe file works, but in another there's an error: "Can't load file X...". X is a dll file. How can i solve this problem? I copied all dlls into project-bin-realese.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the DLLs into the same folder as the EXE.  It you put them in a sub directory then you are going to have to use the `<probing>` element in an app.exe.config file so that the CLR can find them there.

Comment: I have it in the same directory, but i want to use my application in another computers so i only want to use exe file. What should i do?

Comment: You could embed the dlls within the executable file using a third party tool such as SmartAssembly or DeepSea or you could merge the assemblies using IL merge. Alternatively you could create a setup tool and deploy that, or use ClickOnce deployment.

Comment: Is this at all related to the original question?  Google `ilmerge`

Comment: LOL at statically linking in DLL's.  The 'dynamic' part is what separates it from a lib in the first place! =D

Comment: @Ed On .NET, all libraries are DLLs. If you want non-dynamic behaviour you have to use ILMerge to combine them with your EXE.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the dependency on the DLL, then right-click it under "References" in your project and remove it.  If you do need the dependency, then it will need to go to the other computers with the EXE.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are generic for loading dependency libraries. However, it may also depend on how the exe loading the libraries. For example, [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) has a DI engine to load catalog libraries from a specific folder. If the required libraries are not there, you may get similar exception. Check your .exe requirement for its specific dependencies.